# How to use replaceWith properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I've developed some code such that when I click a `<div>`, some element is replaced with an `<input>` element. What I want to know is how I can place back the original `<div>`.

The following code is what I've already tried. Can you help me, please?

```
$('.editar_form').click(function(){
if ($(this).closest('.form-container').children('.nombre_nom').is('div')){

    $('.nombre_nom').replaceWith('<input value = " ' + $('.nombre_nom').text() + ' ">');

} if  ($(this).closest('.form-container').children('.nombre_nom').not('div')){
    alert('no');
    $('.nombre_nom').replaceWith('div');
}
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Does your alert trigger properly? Your second `replaceWith()` is not an element <div>, its just the text 'div'.

Comment: Here mention the div completely or assign html to a variable  $('.nombre_nom').replaceWith('<div>Hello World</div>'); 
For more understanding check this link http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/